# Hover effect on siblings

Tags: css, hover

HTML/CSS:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
ul li:first-child,
ul li:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFq8f/20/) -here is a list having its first-element as default hovered.
 How can I remove hover effect on first child of list when its siblings are hovered?

When other than first `li` child elements are `hover`ed to turn `color` of `first-child` to `black`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSS [doesn't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) a previous sibling selector, the closest you can get would be to use the selector `ul:hover li:not(:hover)` to select all `li` elements that are not currently being hovered over when hovering over the parent `ul` element. You can use that selector to override the other styling and set the `li` elements back to black:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jznen6s2/)

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
  color: #000;
}
ul li:first-child,
ul li:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```